# Как узнать о IDisposable.Dispose() (или подписаться на событие)

Tags: c#, .net

Как узнать о том, что объект интерфейса [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) вызвал метод [Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Что ты хочешь сделать-то?

Comment: Узнать что объект вызвал метод Dispose. Можно было и таймером мониторить... Но это как то по деревянному...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если наследоваться не вариант - то никак. `IDisposable` это не какая-то хитрая системная штука. Это просто интерфейс с одним методом.

Соответственно, вызов `Dispose` - это просто вызов метода. Точно так же вызывается какой-нибудь `IMyInterface.MyMethod()`. Никаких особых событий при этом не происходит.

Comment: Я подозревал это. Но надеялся на лучшее, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, реализовать в нём метод Dispose так, чтобы он вызывал некоторое событие. А вообще, какая-то странная идея.

Comment: Объект не мой, наследоваться не вариант. Это решение мне изветстно.

Answer (score 0):

В книге ["Внедрение зависимостей в .NET" Марка Симана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0), приведен способ под названием "Перехват".

Так, имеем основной класс `ClassA`:

```
class ClassA : IDisposable
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassA.Dispose");
    }
}
```

Используем его соответственно:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        try
        {
            a.Do();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (a != null) a.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод будет такой:

> Do something
>   ClassA.Dispose

Теперь, чтобы добавить код, который будет выполняться до или после метода Dispose, добавляем класс посредник:

```
class ClassB : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _obj;

    public ClassB(IDisposable obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        _obj = obj;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Befor ClassA.Dispose");
        _obj.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("After ClassA.Dispose");
    }
}
```

Использование будет такое:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
        try
        {
            a.Do();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (b != null) b.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно вывод будет:

> Do something
>   Befor ClassA.Dispose
>   ClassA.Dispose
>   After ClassA.Dispose

Таким образом, используя "Перехват" можно добавить код который будет исполняться до или после выполнения метода `Dispose`, что равноценно реализации события внутри класса, за исключением доступа к внутренним переменным (но при необходимости и к ним можно достучаться).

Comment: Решение интересно. Но к сожалению не могу его использовать. Пришлось написать свой класс и принудительно вызывать события при Disopose объекта =(